# What will be the regular expression for alphanumeric characters, space ,french characters and dash?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I just want to know what will be the regex for alphanumeric characters, space french characters and dash. I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE regexp_like(name_elem1,'[^[:alnum:]^[:blank:]^[àâçéèêëîïôûùüÿñæœ]^[\-]]');
```

Please help

Comment: You may add more information about how it doesn't work, what you really want to do and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an Oracle SQL expert and cannot test the solution but I would rather write it the following way:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE regexp_like(name_elem1,'[0-9A-Za-z\ \tàâçéèêëîïôûùüÿñæœ]+');
```

Different sources say that one cannot join regex character classes so I have put them explicitly: `[0-9A-Za-z]` for alnum, `\ \t` for white characters and an extended list of French characters.

Comment: Thanks, and what if i want to include dashes(-) also??

Comment: Add escaped dash i.e. "\-"

Answer (score 0):

If you *want* those characters, then don't use the 'not' expression...and consider case-insensitivity.

`... regexp_like(name_elem1,'[[:alnum:][:blank:][àâçéèêëîïôûùüÿñæœ]]', 'i');`

caveot: this is just looking for any 1 character matching the expression.

Here's the official doc:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix.htm#SQLRF020